# How to check if a string contains HTML code in ASP.NET MVC model validation?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a model string which looks like:

```
bla bla bla <b>asdad</b> bla bla bla bla <u>bla</u> ...
```

My model:

```
public class MyModel {
      [RegularExpression( @"^(<\s*([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?<\s*\/\s*\1\s*>)$", ErrorMessage = "No tag is allowed !")]
      public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to negate above regex ( I know that I didn't use correctly and I don't know how to do this correctly)

I want to **show error** when `Text` contains any match of HTML code, even it has no closed tag, means should occur when met:

`<b>` without `</b>`

`</b>` or similar

How to achieve this with regex ?

Comment: I tried that in regex101 and not working mean that any words that are not html tag are not highlighted

Comment: You'd better make this clear in the title, as well as in this post, not in the comment. That would make it a lot easier for people who are willing to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the regex for that:

```
<(\s*[(\/?)\w+]*)
```

It checks for even if single closing tag is there or opening tag is there, it matches that.

[DEMO here](https://regex101.com/r/mB6qN5/1)

Comment: Ok, it is possible to negate above regex?

Comment: negate means, it should not match html tags (there should not be html tags in string)?

Comment: Yes, exactly...I wish, if possible, to highlight all text that are not between `<` and `>` ...

Comment: for that you can use like: ``^((?![<>]).)*$``

Comment: this doesn't look reliable- it would match "5 is < 10" as a piece of html

Answer (score 0):

The following regex matches if a model string contains no HTML tags:

```
^((?!\<(|\/)[a-z][a-z0-9]*>).)*$
```

The demo is [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/sV9vQ0/1)

Comment: Updated regex. I misunderstood it previously.